# How can I add Monero to wallets such as Atomic/Exodus/Coinomi using the ERC-20 Eth contract address?

Tags: cold-storage, wallet

How can one add a cryptocurrency or token to a non-custodial wallet such as Atomic, Coinomi or Exodus using the ERC-20 contract address instead of storing them online to avoid loss due to hacking or otherwise?

Comment: Those wallets are all custodial. Are you trying to get your Monero off of those wallets?

Answer (score 0):

Coinomi supports every ERC20 token. If the one you want to store isn't already on the "Add tokens - Ethereum" list in the app you can follow the instructions here to manually add the token wallet: https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000009779-how-to-manually-add-an-erc20-token-